# Run PHP Artisan without CD Change Directory

Tags: linux, laravel, laravel-5

I currently have to cd to my project to access `php artisan`

```
cd /var/www/html/project
php artisan
```

Is it possible to access it without the `cd` command by just running `php artisan`?

I tried creating an alias in the `.bashrc` file with no luck:

```
sudo nano .bashrc
```

Added this at the bottom:

```
alias artisan='/var/www/html/project/artisan'
```

Then when I ran `php artisan` it said "Could not open input file: artisan"

Comment: Artisan is a console application that you need it for each of your projects. This per project need, is why you have to change to the specific application directory. I suggest try not to use it globally or with aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Try `alias artisan='php /var/www/html/project/artisan'`
and running this as simply `artisan command`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a shell script like this, because alias didn't support parameters.

```
#!/bin/bash
php ~/projects/your_project/artisan $1 $2
```

Be sure, that you make your shell script executble with

> chmod +x filename.sh